# Feature request: question rating

Tags: feature-request

It's not a secret to everyone that most silly and repeated questions get most number of answers and these silly answers gets way overupvoted. So, there are hordes of, let's call them *not-too-experienced* participants, who never had real experience but just learned few rumors right here and always glad to paste it into 1000's question of the kind.

While really hard guestions just sink to bottom  in seconds as none of these active folks ever able to understand it. At the same time to answer such a question will usually require some efforts, not just utter some platitude like "use PDO and be safe ever" or copy/paste another ugly code snippet.
So, ones who spending some *time* (which costs money), have to be awarded more. May be even with some distinct awards, aside from shameful reputation system.

It would be nice to implement some feature that can mark questions as "trash", "trivial", "good", and "improving our knowledge".

So, it would be nice to divide Stackoverflow into 2 parts: lame Q&A site and place for ones who want to learn and exchange knowledge.

Please, don't tell me of voting system. It doesn't work. May be it would if it will take points for upvoting too, but I doubt though. The reasons for upvoting are far away from question/answer qualities. It's more matter of charity, people tend to *support* each other, encourage others with upvotes, no matter how stupid their answer was.

Comment: I agree to some degree with you, but splitting SO or a question rating system ain't going to help in this. The same problem would manifest after some time on the "advanced" part of the split. The question rating system would only be abused. Just live with it. You've probably been on SO for too long that you end up in seeing easy questions/answers and/or duplicates only.

Comment: You mean like how every question on Programmers that get's tweeted by Joel get's over 200 votes?

Comment: I think you need to visit the [Unanswered](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags) tab more often.  Sincerely, you're needed there.

Comment: @Bill nope, I am not. All these questions not of the kind "I can share my knowledge and show the right way" but of "go sit and dig hard". But isn't it funny: I have dozens of the questions of latter kind right on my job! Any reason I should forget my job and spend considerable amount of time doing someone's else job for free? No wonder they remain unanswered, eh?

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with most of your solutions but I agree that many good questions don't rise above the bad ones.  I would suggest changes to the voting system rep for up/down votes rather than dividing the site up.  Specifically some ideas:

- Remove the penalty for the down-voter on a question.  This will encourage more down voting on bad questions because there is no longer a penalty.
- Allow more than 30 votes per day for users who have achieved vote based tags.

Some things you can do yourself to help:

- Add bounties to good questions where you see limited activity
- Vote up good questions
- Vote down bad ones
- Get enough rep to cast close votes and close bad questions